# Cyclic Supspaces and span

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be a field.  I am to either prove or provide a counter example to the following:

If $T$ is a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$, then for any $v\in V$, $T$-cyclic subspace generated by $v$ is the same as the $T$-cyclic subspace generated by $T(v)$.

I know that if $C=\{ v, T(v), ..., T^k(v)\}$ is a basis for the $T$ cyclic subspace, then $T^{k+1}(v)$ can be expressed as a linear combo of the elements in $C$, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is false for arbitrary T.

Consider V=$\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard basis and define the linear operator T by $T(x,y)=(x,0)$ for any $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Then consider the T-cyclic subspaces of v and T(v) when $v=(0,y)$ for $y\neq 0$. T(v)=(0,0) so the T-cyclic subspace for v is just Span(v) (the y-axis) but the T-cyclic subspace for T(v) is just the origin.

You may be able to prove the theorem if you assume that T is invertible. The basic problem is that your linear operator T might not preserve all of the information about the original vector v, so when you take the T-cyclic subspace generated by T(v) you obtain a smaller subspace of the original vector space.

Comment: I think this is correct.  Thank you.